# Should undergrads list affiliation?

Tags: publications, affiliation

If I am simply an undergraduate of an institution, am I affiliated with it? I do not want to lie about my affiliation but also do not want to permissibly lie by putting "Independent Researcher" if I should in fact list my university.

Comment: Were you an undergraduate there at the time you did the research, or a significant part of it?  Was the research supported by the university in any way (funding, supervised by faculty member, part of a course, etc)?

Comment: Affiliation is in part to let people know how to easily get a hold of you. In that context, it makes sense for an undergrad to list their affiliation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you did the work while you were a student at your university, you should list that university as your affiliation.